# Admin to register User to project

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have been spending some days trying to build this feature. Can you help me with some guidance please ?

Currently I have different project on my platform. Every user can register for any project for free. But now I want to change that. Only admin can register a user to a specific project. And the user can only see the project the admin has registered him too

This is project controller

```rb
class ProjectController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
      @projects = Project.all.order(:tag)
  end

  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @tasks = @project.tasks.order(:tag)

    @joined = false

    if !current_user.nil? && !current_user.projects.nil?
      @joined = current_user.projects.include?(@project)
    end

    @users = @project.users.order('created_at desc').first(10)
  end

  def list
    if !current_user.nil?
      @projects = current_user.projects
    end
  end
end
```

This is my project Model

```rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]

  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, through: :subscriptions, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :content, presence: true

  has_one_attached :image

  def shortname
    name.length > 25? name[0..24] + "..." : name
  end
end
```

This is charge controller

```rb
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def free
    project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    current_user.subscriptions.create(project: project)

    redirect_to project
  end
end
```

this is the subscriptions model

```rb
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm able to do it via the rails console using the charge function

```rb
user_name.subscriptions.create(project: project_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another good option that I've found is to install the gem active_admin. From there I can easily import the Subscription model and register user to a project.